# Return "complex" object in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Settings
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Property { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     public List<SettingsProperty> Properties { get; set; }
 }
```

With my database table looking like this:

```
Id             Property       Value
13             prop1          valueProp1
13             prop2          valueProp2
2              prop1          valueProp1
```

What I want to do is, given an Id, return an object of type Settings and store the properties and values inside the list Properties. So if I fetch records with Id 13, I would want something like this (kind of a json syntax to better explain it):

```
Id = 13
Properties = [{Name = "prop1", Value = "valueProp1"}, {Name = "prop2", Value = "valueProp2"}]
```

I thought I could maybe group results by Id, but this is not working and I can't think of any other way to do this. This is what I have:

```
_context.Settings
.Where(d => d.Id == Id)
.Select(x => new Settings()
{
   Id = x.Id,
   Properties = new List<SettingsProperty>()
   {
      new SettingsProperty()
      {
         Name = x.Property,
         Value = x.Value
      }
   }
 })
 .AsNoTracking()
```

But this only gets me the one record. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Why not just remove `[NotMapped]` and make that a Navigation Property to a SettingsProperty entity?

Comment: It's just SettingsProperty is not an entity. I'm sorry, I'm kind of new to Entity Framework. But is there other way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: But you have a table `(Id,Property,Value)` so just map that to an Entity.

Comment: You can also map complex properties to json